# Open MS Word document with webdav and javascript

Tags: javascript, activex, webdav

I enable Webdav in IIS, and I'm able to open a word document using IE with the below Javascript code:

```
    var objWord = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
    objWord.Visible = true;
    objWord.Documents.Open('//127.0.0.1/Wd/docs/test.docx');
```

but to be able to open the document I need to manually enable "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" from IE internet options, is there any other solution that doesn't need manual configuration?